# How do I make the panel background invisible in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, kubuntu, themes, kde

I hope I am not wrong by asking a Kubuntu question.

Previously there was a desktop theme called Bare Naked.  It is my favorite, but no longer is available.  Is there a way to make the panel background invisible?  If so, how?  I installed a different version of Kubuntu.  Bare naked remained in the configuration apparently, because widgets I have on my desktop remain with invisible backgrounds.  But the panel background became opaque.  Thanks! :scratch: